# Expanding the X-axis using R

Tags: r

there has some issue with my axis, I want to show the full data at the axis but I am not sure how to expand it. This my code.

```
boxplot(Complied_Data$`Stress (N/m2)` ~ Complied_Data$Category,
        main="Stress Distribution of different rates", ylab="Stress (Pa)", 
        xlab="Specimens", notch=TRUE, col="brown1", cex=10)
```

[image: here]

Comment: You may rotate or rebuild the x axis. Also you may use `png` or similar instead of plot window which actually may be seen as a preview. See duplicates.